# identificar boton con on(click

Tags: jquery, input, input-type

soy nuevo en esta vaina, si de pronto tienen una mejor forma de hacerlo, aprecio la colaboracion

Tengo varios formulario creados dianamicamente por un loop (la informacion viene desde BD y puede variar segun el usuario), cada uno tiene un boton de guardar y sus campos respectivos.
busco que cuando se presione cualquier boton de guardar, este tome solo lo que le corresponde a su formulario y envie por ajax a otro php para que este inserte en BD.

tengo esta función:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e){
  var targetID = $(e.target).attr('id').match(/[^\d]+|\d+/g)[1];
  console.log(targetID);  
  boton(targetID);
});
```

para el código de arriba funciona pero quisiera que solo se activara para los botones de guardar, actualmente toma cualquier input.

con este llamado, lo que busco es saber cual es # del botón y así mismo poder saber a que formulario pertenece realizando el llamado a la funcion boton(id) donde id es el numero del boton.

```
function boton(id){

    $('#loginform'+id).submit(function(e) {
      console.log("entre "+id);
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'json/save.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response)
            {
              alert(response);

           }
       });
     });
    }
```

```
html= html +'<form  id="loginform'+id+yd+xd+'">';
  html = html + '<table class="table table-sm table-borderless table-responsable"><tr>';
  html= html +'<td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="actividad'+id+yd+xd+'" id="actividad'+id+yd+xd+'" placeholder="*Actividad"/></td>';
  html= html +'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="meta'+id+yd+xd+'" id="meta'+id+yd+xd+'"placeholder="*Meta anual"/></td> ';
  html= html +'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="medida'+id+yd+xd+'" id="medida'+id+yd+xd+'"placeholder="*Und. Medida"/></td> ';
  html= html +'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="proyecto'+id+yd+xd+'" id="proyecto'+id+yd+xd+'"placeholder="Nombre proyecto/actividad"/></td> ';
  html= html + '<td><select title="*Cronograma" class="selectpicker" name="state'+id+yd+xd+'" id="state'+id+yd+xd+'" multiple>';
  html= html + '        <option>Enero</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Febrero</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Marzo</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Abril</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Mayo</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Junio</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Julio</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Agosto</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Septiembre</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Octubre</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Noviembre</option>';
  html= html + '        <option>Diciembre</option>';
  html= html + '      </select> </td>';
  html = html + '<td><button type="button" name="add'+id+yd+xd+'" id="add'+id+yd+xd+'" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>  ';
  html = html + '</tr>  ';
  html = html + '</table> '; 
  html= html + '</form> ';
  html= html + '<div  style="text-align:center"><button class="mb-2" name="loginBtn'+id+yd+xd+'" id="loginBtn'+id+yd+xd+'">Guardar</button></td></div>';
```

Comment: Parece que el prefijo **add** usado al crear el id de los buttons **no se usa al crear el id** de los forms de modo que los llamados no son consistentes. tienes `'#loginform'+id` en un lado y ese id trae el prefijo add mientras que en la declaración tienes: `'<form  id="loginform'+id+yd+xd+'">'` sin el add

Comment: este boton add es para otra funcion, el que hace la funcion de enviar el contenido del formulario es el de abajo "loginBtn"

Comment: Acabo de revisar y noté que usas una expresión regular para eliminar el prefijo (no obstante puede ser insuficiente porque tienes tres variables que aportan dígitos y no se si contengan separadores que garanticen no sobreescritura de valores). Prueba a cambiar: `$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e){` por `$(document).on('click', '.save', function(e){` y pones la clase save a los botones guardar así: `<button class="mb-2 save"`

Comment: Quevedo, gracias, al final con el ID del boton y la expresion regular pude referenciar a los inputs de ese form, no lo pude hacer que los tomara serializado sino que armando el Json para el ajax, ya me funciono, supongo que no es la mejor forma pero funciona. gracias por el codigo, voy a probarlo en otra pagina para ver que pasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacrlo con Ajax de esta forma:

AJAX:

```
function update_click(clicked_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mi-form.php?variable="+clicked_id,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(){
          // Lo que se hará antes de enviar
      },
      success: function(data){
          // Lo que se hará cuando el proceso haya sido completado
      },
      error: function(data){
          // Lo que se hará cuando el proceso haya sido completado
          console.log("Hubo un error.");
      }
    });
return false; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="mb-2" name="loginBtn'+id+yd+xd+'" id="loginBtn'+id+yd+xd+'" onClick="update_click(this.id)">Guardar</button>
```

Entonces, tienes:

> url: "mi-form.php?variable="+clicked_id

Para, dependiendo del ID se ejecute una función en el archivo ajax 'mi-form.php'

Pero te recomiendo hagas algo así:

mi-form.php

```
if(isset($_POST['actividad']) && !empty($_POST['actividad'])){
    // Actualizar en la BBDD
}

if(isset($_POST['meta']) && !empty($_POST['meta'])){
    // Actualizar en la BBDD
}

// Y así con todas
```

De este modo solamente se actualizaran/insertarán los datos que contengan información.

Si tienes dudas espero tus comentarios, espero te sirva :D

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!!!. hice la prueba queriendo ver que iba en data y no me muestra nada 
`function update_click(clicked_id){
  console.log($(this).serialize());
}`